# Duplicate questions between the StackExchange sites?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure how to "ask the same question" or even if this is allowed on different affiliate sites from StackExchange.

For example, my question on Ask Ubuntu, which is an affiliate site: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162155/how-to-properly-debug-failures-with-do-release-upgrade

I would like to have this question here on Serverfault too. But I'm not sure if reposting on Serverfault would violate any rules.

If yes, how can we fix this issue? Give a broader audience to a question that may be relevant in other affiliate sites?

Answer (score 7):

First: Thanks for asking!

That said: Crossposting is not allowed on the SE network, and AskUbuntu is no different in that regard. Either flag on AskUbuntu for migration or let it live there. I am not an Ubuntu expert, but it might be a better fit on the other site because I would rather reinstall a production system in a known clean and good state then go through the hassle of an in-place upgrade - doing these kind of upgrades appear to be to be more useful for end users.